# How to show dictionary result of a Google search?

Tags: dictionary, google-search

When I put 'chromosome' in Google, it shows the meaning, phonetic notation, usage of 'chromosome' among other things. I think it is quit useful and I use this function to look up words often. But not all words you put in the engine give you the dictionary result, I am wondering if there is a way to impose Google to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix `define` to your search query to get definitions.

For example,

```
define chromosome
```